# How can I get the value from Elementor Widget control field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I'm working on an Elementor custom widget with basic fields for text.  I need to grab the value of one field only in order to process an ajax request that will then populate the rest of the fields.  I'm using JavaScript mutations to do so. The problem I am having in the admin editor is that the nodes do not show the values in the dom, only the placeholder content.  Is there a way to enable this in the editor or do I need to go a different route to capture user input?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Share a link !

Comment: This is for the admin editor, I wouldn't be able to.